# What font is this

Tags: style

[image]

I like the font used on the picture above because it's easy on the eyes.

Can somebody help me determine the font name used?

Comment: A Google search on the first sentence resulted in [this](https://www.sma.de/fileadmin/Partner/Solaracademy/Downloads/EN/Planning%20and%20Design%20for%20small%20and%20medium%20PV-Plants_EN-123610_web.pdf) (link to PDF). It's from the "SMA Solar Academy."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about how to write etc. Seems more like it should be on Graphic Design Stack Exchange. See these guidelines: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366

Answer (score 2):

While a 100% certain answer would require comparing fonts until an exact match is found, I believe the font **Calibri** is very close to what you are looking for. It is not the exact font, as the `g`'s are different, but the look is very close.

Some other close comparisons (with the correct `g`): Ebrima, Microsoft JhengHei, Microsoft Tai Le, Univers, and Vrinda.